# My prefix ends fast

Tags: riddle, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix ends fast
>   My suffix is behind mast
>   My infix is a type of daisy
>   I'm oriental (and this last rhyme is lazy)

Comment: Bass is a poet and he doesn't even realize it.

Comment: Oh, trust me, I do know it; English isn’t my first language, so I have to verify each rhyme with a dictionary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are ...

> **Eastern**.

My prefix ends fast

> The festival of **Easter** ends Lent, the time of fasting.

My suffix is behind mast

> The **stern** is the rear part of a ship.

My infix is a type of daisy

> An **aster** is a kind of daisy. (Or is it the other way round?)

I'm oriental (and this last rhyme is lazy)

> Oriental means **Eastern**.

Comment: Yup, that's it, exactly. I'm secretly not an actual expert on daisy taxonomy, so I had to use the [ultimate source of absolute truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositae), from which I understood that "daisies" is the common (as in unscientific) name of the family Compositae, which recently got their scientific name changed to the A-word derivative. The A-word then is the [type genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_genus) of that family, and then again, the type *species* of the A-word genus is the European Michaelmas-daisy. So, maybe, "yes, it's the other way around, too"?

Comment: I was a bit confused when I looked this up. To me, asters are colourful ornamental flowers that blossom in autumn and daisies are the small white and yellow flowers that grow on the lawn. To my non-botanical mind these are two different flowers. Apparently either daisies or asters may refer to the family. ("Aster" is a staple of German crosswords, where it is invariably clued as "autumn flower".)

Comment: Checking after the fact, there seems to be two five-star answers to the crossword clue [kind of daisy (5)](https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/Kind-of-daisy-(5)), the other being ”oxeye”, which still doesn’t add any clarity to the fact, but at least it offers an easy fix to the riddle, if such is needed. As an unrelated aside, I originally planned to have the suffix include one more letter, since that was the maximal overlap I could find for four unrelated words. Sadly, using the non-maximal word made for a much better puzzle :-)

Comment: Ox-eye was the first thig I thought of (without looking it up), but it makes a poor infix. Just to be clear:I don't think your puzzle needs to be fixed; The parenthetical remark about the aster was just to show my confusion.In hindsight,I should have left it out.

Answer (score 4):

Probably incorrect:

> Checkmate

My prefix ends fast

> prefix = check - like a tick mark denotes something which has been done/finished

My suffix is behind mast

> suffix = mate - before the mast is a sailors term meaning all the common sailors. Therefore all the other crew members with some rank are 'behind the mast'. Mate is a sailor's rank

My infix is a type of daisy

> No idea

I'm oriental (and this last rhyme is lazy)

> Chess came from the East therefore is oriental. Also usually it is very slow paced.

Comment: I don’t think there’s *anything* I intended in this answer, remarkably good work getting so far! +1! (How fortunate for me that the riley-riddle template is so overspecified with the triple wordplays; had you managed to fit in the bit about the daisies, I’d have been forced to seriously consider accepting this answer even though it was’t the intended one.)

Comment: @Bass I had the same feeling but nevertheless decided to post it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are:

> Aster

My prefix ends fast

> ast ends fast

My suffix is behind mast

> er can be put behind mast to form master

My infix is a type of daisy

> an aster is a type of daisy

I'm oriental (and this last rhyme is lazy)

> the aster is native to eastern asia

Comment: I like this, I hope this is the one. Very clever riddle if so

Comment: Oh wow, this is brilliant! The whole word doesn’t usually count as the infix, but otherwise, quite flawless!