# I have not a flower

Tags: riddle

> People used to say me if their day was sour.
>
> They would always say that I have not a flower.
>
> But when you are my modern form, you are this flower’s rhyme.
>
> For my modern derivation happens when you waste your time.

What archaic interjection am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having just perused wikipedia on the taxonomy of asters, I think you must be

> Lackadaisy

Which comes (approximately) from

> ”alack (woe) the day” via ”lackaday”

and in its modern form

> ”lackadaisical” means lazy. And that, in turn, rhymes with daisy.

Comment: Wow fast.  In fact I was somewhat inspired by [your question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/63698/46277).  Would you mind adding explanations since this is an unused word.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is:

> lackadaisy

because:

> The archaic meaning of lackadaisy is sorrow, or regret

and

> lack-a-daisy, literally means to be without a daisy

Now, in modern meaning

> lackadaisy means indifference or languor

Or what might be described as

> lazy, which rhymes with lackadaisy

And

> being lazy, or lazing, wastes time

Comment: Dammit, @Bass got there while I was typing this

Comment: Fastest iphone typist in the west, whee! :-)